# In a Jest test where does the window object come from?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a simple Jest test:

```
describe('test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {});
  it('test', function() {
    console.log(window.document); //a real or nearly real document
  });
});
```

I'm requiring a few modules e.g. bootstrap - but nothing that looks like it might provide a window object - with a document object on it.

My question is - who/what is providing this window (and window.document) object? The window object is similar to a browser window - albeit missing one or two methods. But I don't see who is providing it. I don't know enough about node.js and webpack (the tests are being built with webpack) to know where to start.

It isn't ReactDOM. Is it Jest? Or node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On quick inspection, I think it's [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Based on [this](http://marmelab.com/blog/2015/06/24/jest-in-practice.html) blog post:

> It’s simple, standard and standalone (based on JSDom and build on top
>   of Jasmine).

Looking at the [package.json](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/package.json) in the [jest repository](https://github.com/facebook/jest),

```
"dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^1.1.1",
    "cover": "^0.2.9",
    "diff": "^2.1.1",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.3",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^12.0.2",
    "jest-environment-node": "^12.0.2",
    "jest-haste-map": "^12.0.2",
    "jest-jasmine1": "^12.0.2",
    "jest-jasmine2": "^12.0.2",
    "jest-mock": "^12.0.2",
    "jest-util": "^12.0.2",
    "json-stable-stringify": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash.template": "^4.2.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "optimist": "^0.6.1",
    "resolve": "^1.1.6",
    "sane": "^1.2.0",
    "which": "^1.1.1",
    "worker-farm": "^1.3.1"
  },
```

Comment: It is jsdom. Thanks.